# NestJS - How to add a dynamic routing to the controller?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have the following problem. Let's say I have an array of routes & paths to static resources, e.g.

```
const routes = [{ url: '/', path: 'assets/www' }]
```

What I would like to do is to create a set of dynamic routes to serve static resources. In express application I would do smth like:

```
const router = express.Router();    
routes.forEach(route => {
   router.use(route.url, express.static(path.join(__dirname, route.path)))
})
```

But is it possible to create such a logic inside a NestJS controller?

```
@Controller()
export class ItemsController {
  constructor() {}

  @Get()
  findAll() {}

  @Get(':id')
  findOne() {}

  ....
}
```

As far as I can see all HTTP request handlers should be predefined using the corresponding decorators.

Comment: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1438

Comment: Thank you sir! This article was helpful!

Answer (score 7):

I would opt for an approach where you create your controllers fully dynamic. This is not natively supported in Nest, but you can actually create dynamic controllers and dynamic services using a mixin approach (what is actually quite common), also see this answer at [GitHub](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1438#issuecomment-872012841):

```js
import { Post, Get, Controller } from '@nestjs/common';

interface Options {
  basePath: string
  entityName: string // you could even pass down DTO classes here, for maximum flexibility.
  providerName: string
}

// this service is generated dynamically as well
// preferably use a custom providerName.
interface DynamicService {
  foo: () => void
  bar: () => void
}

export const createDynamicController = (controllerOptions: Options) => {

  @Controller(controllerOptions.basePath)
  class MyController {

    constructor(
      @Inject(options.providerName) myProvider: DynamicProvider
    ){}

    @Get(options.entityName)
    findOne(){
      return this.myProvider.foo()
    }

    @Post(options.entityName)
    create(){
      return this.myProvider.foo()
    }

  }

  
  return MyController
}
```

Using that approach you can create all controllers in theory dynamically, but it asks a bit more about understanding of the NestJS dependency tree.

You can now create the controller like:

```js
{
   controllers: [createDynamicController({
     basePath: 'foo',
     entityName: 'barz',
     providerName: 'custom-provider-name'
    })
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have a dynamic controller -> with say Parameters identifiers -> the as if it were like an event handler id... (not really just using that as an way to think of the process.)

Then in your the connected service -> you can have the 5 crud operations however in your service you inject the static resources -> and use that Identifier to route the call.

```
query dto

export class QueryDto {
  readonly params?: any[];
  readonly body: any;
}
```

```
controller

 @Post(':serviceId')
  async create(@Param('serviceId') serviceId: string, @Body() queryDto: QueryDto) {
    return await this.rootService.create(serviceId, queryDto);
  }
```

```
inside your root service
 // childService = used to route the request dynamically ->
 // body = your body or if you dont need a body this is where any parameters would go. which is why it's any (for if it was a get)
 // params last => incase your doing a put or something where you need a body and parameters -> but it also allows it to be optional.

 async create(childService: string, data: any, params: any[]): Promise<any> {
    if (!id) {
      return await this[childService].create(data.body, ...data.params).exec() 
    }
```

just an idea, but if everything static then this should do it for you. just use the root service as a passthrough. from the single controller -> to the various services.

Answer (score 0):

You really can have access to express instance of nestjs without context to configure routes:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
const httpAdapter = app.getHttpAdapter();

const expressApp = httpAdapter.getInstance();
expressApp.use('/your_route', some.middleware());
```

OR in context of class:

```
export class CatsService {
  constructor(private adapterHost: HttpAdapterHost) {
     const httpAdapter = adapterHost.httpAdapter;
     const app = httpAdapter.getInstance();

     app.use('/your_route', some.middleware());
  }
}
```

You can read more here:
https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/http-adapter